# Why does navigating to a Nested Graph will show the last active fragment instead of its startDestination?

Tags: android

A bit contexts, i'm using `NavigationView`, so the navigation graph is actually tied/matched with my menu file.

First, here is my navigation graph looks like

```xml
<navigation
  app:startDestination="@+id/nav__fragment_a">
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav__fragment_a"/>
  
  <navigation
    android:id="@+id/nav__navigation_b"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav__fragment_b">
    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/nav__fragment_b">
      <action
        android:id="@+id/nav__action_fragment__b_to_b1"
        app:destination="@id/nav__fragment_b1"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/nav__fragment_b1"/>
  </navigation>
</navigation>
```

Here my menu file

```xml
<menu>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/nav__fragment_a"/>
    
  <item
    android:id="@+id/nav__navigation_b"/>
</menu>
```

I want to know, why does clicking the `@id/nav__navigation_b` menu in `NavigationView` will show the `@id/nav__fragment_b1`, in the last of this scenes

-> from `@id/nav__fragment_a`

-> navigate to `@id/nav__navigation_b` (by clicking a menu in NavigationView) -- it is correct showing the `@id/nav__fragment_b` fragment

-> navigate to `@id/nav__fragment_b1` (manually with click listener)

-> navigate to `@id/nav__fragment_a` (by clicking a menu in NavigationView)

-> navigate to `@id/nav__navigation_b` (by clicking a menu in NavigationView) -- the result i didn't expect

The last scene, it is showing `@id/nav__fragment_b1` instead of the `@id/nav__fragment_b` by default.

This is actually a problem for me, but i want to know the reason first. Maybe i can override the menu click listener, i didn't try it yet, but i really don't want it.

Comment: It sounds like your NavigationView is correctly using the [multiple back stacks feature](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f) to save the back stack for each item.